# Disable form inputs after ajax submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that submits via Ajax. After the user sends the form, the text changes displaying the form was sent successfully and then shows the form filled out. I want to display the form but I don't want them to re-submit the form so I want to disable the inputs as well as the submit button. I tried adding: `$('#submit_btn').className +=" disabled"` to the ajax script but it just made the page refresh without submitting anything.

The ajax script is as follows:

```
    $(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  $('input.text-input').css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
  $('input.text-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFDDAA"});
  });
  $('input.text-input').blur(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
  });

  $(".button").click(function() {
        // validate and process form
        // first hide any error messages
    $('.error').hide();

        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("inputemail").val();
        var phone = $("inputphone").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
        //alert (dataString);return false;

        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/webParts/contact-form.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#myModalLabel').html("<h3 class='text-success' id='myModalLabel'>Contact Form Submitted!</h3>")
        $('#myModalSmall').html("<p class='muted'>Your submiessions are below. We will be contacting you soon, you may now close this window.</p>")
        $('#submit_btn').className +=" disabled"
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#message').append("<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>");
        });
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
runOnLoad(function(){
  $("input#name").select().focus();
});
```

How could I possibly disable the inputs and button after a successful form submission?

http://jsfiddle.net/gY9xS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's a lot simpler than what you're trying to do, you don't need to disable the inputs, simply cancel the submit after the ajax request:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Put it inside the success handler of your ajax request.

If you want to disable the submit button, replace this wrong thing:

```
$('#submit_btn').className +=" disabled"
```

With:

```
$('#submit_btn').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I will accept this answer as soon as I am able to. But, `$('#submit_btn).prop("disabled", true);` still results in a page refresh. I am accepting the answer because the first part of your answer does in fact prevent multiple database submissions.

Comment: Something else must be causing the page refresh, setting a class or property won't do it.

Comment: @user, you miscopied the code: there's a missing the closing single quote sign in your selector: `$('#submit_btn).prop("disabled", true);`, just after `submit_btn`. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, i just disabled the submit button and shows some progress message

```
    function submitForm(formObj) {

        // Validate form
        // if (formObj.email.value === '') {
        //     alert('Please enter a email');
        //     return false;
        // }

        formObj.submit.disabled = true;
        formObj.submit.value = 'Log In...';
        return true;
    }


     <form class="form-login" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
      method="POST" action="/login"   onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
      ......
      <input type="submit" id="login-submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
      </form>
```